# Can these timer switches (relays) handle DC or will they arc?

Tags: switches, relay, timer, 12v, arc

I'm looking to add timer functionality to a 12V agricultural project. It's to turn a light and heat mat on and off at the appropriate times.

I was kicking around eBay and found a few timer switch relay gizmos that look like they'll work but I have one major concern and that is using AC switches in a DC system and getting arcing which would be very bad.

All the products will run on 12V but I'm not sure if the switching side can do DC.

[Timer 1](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/313431840167?var=612290715840)

[Timer 2](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/314600381861?hash=item493fa4dda5%3Ag%3APmAAAOSwttdkZyMw&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAAwE3GTQQpwwuyK8PBgActvXo7Hi5jVBMiAflrdqKnCBMsnqHQ1PckTFnLTn4rk7gKAx%2BRdnmH4S3RFxTTkRoFY%2BrXa3uQpY%2F6lzBEe5p6LNXZDnjPOg9r%2B%2B6oDDpcaAcVcz64n%2BCiJp88sl6bj5KP0SbGLTeKIfWBxPk9X7fqo9esZUqDHCP3FIJHqrscfWPtnwIKCjum%2FaHtGH4xf27%2FN3LigPqzMuNhJNTMMcH36nXzCaR6PypqUFQafgrqBcXlCA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR9LDwf--Yg&var=613138685590)

[Timer 3](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/374842519193?hash=item57465aee99:g:SNIAAOSwDe1kw9vh&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4IX38INFKNrKi0Q8RwiJ65Zjh2rk1Lxd%2F0yglUZF7PEacwbLM5zoLIuclE0TMSKLaYbQFjG34BfxUTxTIFVsE17%2FKiyiVJKT1RCNEljVNLqyyHM24a32Jl05GjtyJfQ2iJ03zTlQqY%2Byew1spPA8ETPeAyEEtk%2Bfe3NNmg1iiysaUysXTPwFdpcflM8hIqEKXtTbL6W5XmhbMFfRi5a%2F83i7TiCd18j7SePp7pBWOjBasR%2FlTX9e30DUSi0Z2SgA3nszMXySDKwaFZAd9aQ865TXp38VZOn%2FUZYDu6DiU9ZM%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR9DDwf--Yg)

[Timer 4](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/404431340680?hash=item5e29fc8488:g:nY0AAOSw1-Bk1FVr&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAAwMwEdo2PqXAA1tYbcvSNCCtwEVSGWmjRD%2BT%2B5GVdwTF%2FDC%2FOteOvJWqrwxwTdyC5H5d3EWea0iXNQjRNPtKc2QZAl8xTT%2BDHiBqgCneXM3Ct%2BbQgfVIyb5QOGqYLwS2jMTUorlu6uvbPvTNznl02M%2FCQIDqVb0T%2BT7iAicqU4UAD5z0Sv7fe%2FbXBrGtGvTnxBY2zuKG8zY%2FiJYEIRcFzsLbFgJiEZy3UyqWBEB38n4vDll7ixBLjJECMxBQeS8fXtw%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR8zDwf--Yg)

Comment: So use those timers to drive DC rated relays - easily found in cars rated up to 100A...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply mate. I guess I wanted to know if using the built in relays is possible first. Cheers

Comment: Most relays can handle DC but only up to a certain current. So you need to specify the current consumption of the device. For higher currents, a SSR might perhaps be more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TM-619-4](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/374842519193?hash=item57465aee99:g:SNIAAOSwDe1kw9vh&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAAA4IX38INFKNrKi0Q8RwiJ65Zjh2rk1Lxd%2F0yglUZF7PEacwbLM5zoLIuclE0TMSKLaYbQFjG34BfxUTxTIFVsE17%2FKiyiVJKT1RCNEljVNLqyyHM24a32Jl05GjtyJfQ2iJ03zTlQqY%2Byew1spPA8ETPeAyEEtk%2Bfe3NNmg1iiysaUysXTPwFdpcflM8hIqEKXtTbL6W5XmhbMFfRi5a%2F83i7TiCd18j7SePp7pBWOjBasR%2FlTX9e30DUSi0Z2SgA3nszMXySDKwaFZAd9aQ865TXp38VZOn%2FUZYDu6DiU9ZM%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR9DDwf--Yg) timer (Timer 3) you've linked specifies both AC and DC output switching ratings:

- 250 VAC 50/60 Hz: 16 A
- 30 VDC: 20 A

See the image of the backside:
[image]

The same timer module, but from a different brand (Frontier Digital Timer TM619, [Datasheet](https://4.imimg.com/data4/TA/UB/MY-402472/digital-timer.pdf)), also specifies AC and DC switching ratings.

[image]

Comment: I must have missed it. That's great, exactly the comfort I need to go forward. Thanks so much Velvel and thanks for going the extra mile grabbing that datasheet for the Frontier device. Legend!

Answer (score 0):

Without taking the products apart and looking at the relay ratings it's impossible to tell, but *typically* relays and switches rated for mains are good for 24 to 30V resistive loads at the same (or similar, say 2/3) current. You can put a diode across the load if there is some inductance, stray or otherwise.

It is possible that your 'light' load will have inrush that could cause the contacts to stick, depending on what it is (if it's LED it might have a capacitor, if its incandescent it will have significant inrush). There are separate ratings for that kind of load ('TV' and tungsten loads), and some relays are not so rated.

Arcing is much more of an issue with higher voltages than your 12VDC.

Comment: Thanks Spehro, yeah I would probably be comfortable using low resistive loads, maybe 2A max for the heat mat. Interesting about inrush currents from different loads lending to arcing. I'm just having a look and incandescent is a resistive load, why do they have big inrush? I would of assumed that capacitive loads would be worse